# Swift 4, reading byte data

Tags: objective-c, swift4, inputstream, outputstream

so I recently update my IMAC and `Xcode`, after updating part of my code wasn't running as its supposed to it. Here is where I originally check messages.

```
func checkForMessages() {
    while true {
        if inputBuffer.length < 4 {
            return
        }
        var msgLength = (inputBuffer.bytes).load(as: UInt32.self)
        msgLength = UInt32(bigEndian: msgLength)
        print("msgLength = \(msgLength)")
        print("inputBuffer Length = \(inputBuffer.length)")
        print("inputBuffer = \(inputBuffer)")
        if inputBuffer.length < msgLength {
            return
        }
        //print("data = \(inputBuffer.subdata(with: NSRange(location: 4, length: Int(msgLength))))")
        if inputBuffer.length < msgLength + 4 {
            return
        }
        let message: Data? = inputBuffer.subdata(with: NSRange(location: 4, length: Int(msgLength)))
        processMessage(message!)
        let amtRemaining: Int = inputBuffer.length - Int(msgLength) - 4
        if amtRemaining == 0 {
            inputBuffer = NSMutableData()
        }
        else {
            print("Creating input buffer of length \(amtRemaining)")
            inputBuffer = NSMutableData(bytes: inputBuffer.bytes + 4 + Int(msgLength), length: amtRemaining)
        }
    }
}
```

and then the process message function

```
func processMessage(_ data: Data) {

    let reader = MessageReader(data: data)
    print("this is the message data\(data)")
    let msgType  = reader?.readByte().hashValue
}
```

and then the actually MessageReader, its in `Objective C`, since I pulled it off the internet a while ago. Its been working fine for me ever since. Until now.

```
#import "MessageReader.h"

@implementation MessageReader

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
      _data = data;
      _offset = 0;
}
return self;
}

- (unsigned char)readByte {
    unsigned char retval = *((unsigned char *) (_data.bytes + _offset));
    _offset += sizeof(unsigned char);
    return retval;
}

- (int)readInt {
    int retval = *((unsigned int *) (_data.bytes + _offset));
   retval = ntohl(retval);
   _offset += sizeof(unsigned int);
   return retval;
}

- (NSString *)readString {
   int strLen = [self readInt];
   NSString *retval = [NSString stringWithCString:_data.bytes + _offset encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   _offset += strLen;
   return retval;
}

- (void)dealloc {
}

@end
```

Now the issue is that instead of returning the number for say “1” or “2”, “30”, etc. its returning some huge number like 1836718193728. I believe the issue lies in the messageReader, readByte function.

Comment: "part of my code wasn't running as its supposed to it" And what happens now? What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry I thought I added what was going on, so Ive been debugging the entire code. And found that the error is occuring in readByte, for example. Server sends value of “1” and then when converting from UInt8 to Int, ends up with value of like “1837619902737” instead of “1”, these numbers arent direct but the same concept applies.

Comment: So reader?.readByte().hasValue is returning a huge number instead of like “1” or “20” etc.

Comment: Could you update your question with that info (more visible than in comments)? Also, could it be that it's not BigEndian anymore?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, ***`reader?.readByte().hasValue` is returning a huge number***. (I believe ***`hasValue`*** is just a typo and its ***`hashValue`***.)

That's a possible behavior of `hashValue`.

Are you using `hashValue` as if it's a `UInt8` to `Int` conversion tool?

It's wrong. The property `hashValue` is (and should be) implemented to return some `Int` value which fulfills one axiom:

```
where a == b, a.hashValue == b.hashValue
```

In older versions of Swift, `UInt8.hashValue` may have returned the same value of type `Int`, but you should not rely on such an implementation detail that is not documented. A slight change of implementation would lead to different results.

And in fact, Swift 4.2 has changed the implementation of `hashValue` drastically.

[SE-0206 Hashable Enhancements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md)

You may need to fix all parts of your project using `hashValue`.
Usually, you use `Int.init(_:)` to convert `UInt8` to `Int`.

In a context like Optional Chaining as shown in your `let msgType`, you may need to write something like this.

```
    let msgType = (reader?.getByte()).map{Int($0)}
```

If you have many parts using `hashValue` wrongly, better write an extension:

```
extension UInt8 {
    var integerValue: Int {
        return Int(self)
    }
}

    let msgType = reader?.getByte().integerValue
```

Generally, you should better not include such wrong hacks in your project.